# rec'd IPSEC packet has invalid spi

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I have setup a lab to play with DMVPN and EIGRP. Everything works perfectly fine until I test things by shutting down redundant ports. Once I do that the DMVPNs never recover even after restoring all ports. I get the error shown below from each "site" on each Hub every minute(rate limited to 1 minute iirc). I understand that this is because ipsec SAs are out of sync but I would think there would be a way for them to recover automatically. What can be done to synchronize these?

```
%CRYPTO-4-RECVD_PKT_INV_SPI: decaps: rec'd IPSEC packet has invalid spi for destaddr=1.1.1.2, prot=50, spi=0xE6F73833(3874961459), srcaddr=2.200.2.200



crypto isakmp policy 10
 encr aes
 authentication pre-share
crypto isakmp key test address 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
crypto isakmp invalid-spi-recovery
crypto ipsec transform-set DefaultCrypto esp-aes
crypto ipsec profile DMVPN
 set transform-set DefaultCrypto
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple diagram and the configs for your hub and spoke routers?

Comment: That particular debug messages is 99% of the time a function of mismatched encryption domains.  I explain it a bit more verbosely in [this Q&A](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10245/why-do-multi-line-crypto-acls-create-instability-in-vpn-tunnels).  If you could provide the out put of "show ipsec sa" for the involved hub and spoke(s), that will helps us identify the problem.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the invalid SPI recovery command only works with static crypto maps (and VTI) where the VPN peer is defined. It doesn't work with dynamic crypto maps or mGRE with dynamic NHRP (DMVPN).

If the problem persists, run ISAKMP and IPsec debug at each VPN peer and examine the router logs for specifics. Consider Cisco Embedded Event Manager (EEM) as well for troubleshooting.

Note as well for routing issues: there could be multiple instances of the same error message for the same VPN flow. The convergence time as a result is affected by SA expire setting from the source. In addition the Dead Peer Detection could affect routing convergence and VPN connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you manually clear the SPI from the CLI on the devices that are experiencing the invalid SPI? Do the SAs recover automatically then?

```
clear crypto sa entry 1.1.1.2 esp $spi
```

Replace $spi with the SPI value found from `show crypto ipsec sa`

My hunch is that the SAs are getting out of sync but have lengthy default timers (isakmp is 24h by default, ipsec sa is 8h by default) thus they won't clear unless manual intervention is executed before those default timers expire.

Please post your full config and also provide IPSec outputs `show crypto sa`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the IOS is too old, bug CSCsq59183 incorrectly shows those messages.

It may also help us to help you if you provide the DMVPN configuration (at least, the Tunnel interface config) of HUB and at least one SPOKE.